# Is 'how come the sky is blue?' considered proper English?

Tags: word-usage

I intensely despise 'how come' but I see it quite regularly.

Is it considered proper English?

Comment: You can despise it all you like, but it's normal colloquial English.  It differs from 'Why?' in that you don't have to invert the rest of the sentence. "You didn't come to the meeting.  How come?" --> "How come you didn't come to the meeting?"

Comment: @DavidGarner I think this comment is unnecessary, the already accepted answer explains it better.

Comment: That answer wasn't there when I was typing my comment.  Anyway, I felt that 'intensely despise' needed to be addressed.

Comment: @DavidGarner So you have to downote the question because I used the word _despise_? Despise is a perfectly acceptable word. It's not my fault you don't like it.

Comment: I didn't downvote your question: in fact, I've *never* downvoted a question on this site. But to expand: you can despise a man for betraying his family, his friends or his country, if you like.  To despise a commonly-used expression is a bit dramatic.

Comment: @Daft For future reference, starting a post by saying that you "intensely despise" a commonly accepted usage makes it sound like the post is a complaint about a pet peeve instead of an actual question.

Comment: How come you despise it?

Comment: One person's *proper English* is another person's improper English or not-English-at-all. And then there's evolution...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's proper English, though informal.

You'll find it in the greatest writers, because people use it :-)

> > **Vineland, Thomas Pynchon** - 2012,
> >
> > "**How come** none are listed as federal
> >     fugitives?”

Answer (score 0):

I think the phrase derives from "how came it to be that..." It is no more strange than any other shortening of a phrase.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. This answer is a good start, but perhaps you can give a link to where you found this information.  Generally, we try to steer clear of opinion-based answers.